# SQL-Change values based on foreign keys (Input/Output)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, foreign-keys

I am trying to make an MS SQL database, and I am quite new to this.
Lets say I have tables with columns

```
Table1=[Client_ID, Client_Name]
Table2=[Product, Client_ID]. (Client_ID is a FK to Table1)
```

Now I want to update data in `Table 2` and I already have some info in `Table 1`. Is there a way to insert into `T2` if I only know `Product` and `Client_Name`? (Somehow lookup `client_ID` in first table based on his name) What if I dont have that specific client in `Table1` yet, can he be inserted during the insertion in `T2`?

Also I need to grab the data from `T2`, but I would want to see a table that is `[Product, Client_Name]`. Is that kind of lookup/replace possible in SQL?

I know I could try to solve these problems beforehand - I'm using Excel as a frontend for accessing my DB, but I hope there is an easier way to do this with SQL itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert into Table 2 as follows

```
'You are passing @Product, @Client_Name

'First look for whether client name is present in table1
declare @clientId as integer;

select @clientId =Client_ID from Table1 where Client_Name=@Client_Name

if @clientId >0 'When there is client name in Table1
begin
insert into table2
values(@Product, @clientId)
end

else 'There is no client name, so we have to insert client name first then gets its id
begin

insert into table1
values(@Client_Name)

'Get id of newly added client, you can done this many way, but here is the simplest way like previous

select @clientId=Client_ID from Table1 where Client_Name=@Client_Name

'Now insert into table2
insert into table2
values(@Product, @clientId)

end
```

You can get the data the way you wanted by using Join

```
Select Table2.Product, Table1.Client_Name from table1 inner join table2 on table1.Client_ID = table2.Client_ID
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Abhith! I knew this should be possible! :)